# Java debug error

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

I wonder if anyone can help - I have this error showing recently when debugging in eclipse - what doe it mean by resource, an imported package or the location of some java files ?

Can't find resource for bundle sun.awt.resources.awt, key AWT.EventQueueClass

MissingResourceException (id =45)

I also get an option to "edit source lookup path"  on the debug tab.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but I think it looks like you're missing something in your version of Java, or Eclipse can't find part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of Eclipse? If not, try upgrading, or if you're using a development build, use a production build.